# Capitalized font with special characters does not fit on NavBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uilabel, uinavigationbar

Here is an example of the font in the Navigation Bar

[image]

The exact phrase should be "ONDE VOCÊ ESTÁ"

The it is cutting the "Ê" and "Á".

The font I am using is Intro Condensed Light and a free version can be found here: http://www.fontfabric.com/intro-condensed-free/

Any idea how to solve this? Other fonts works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Why it shows up this way]

This font was created incorrectly, as is common with free fonts. You can see that the ¨in this example goes outside the range of the character so it isn't rendered.

Here is a google font which is a close match and should be done properly.

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Alegreya+Sans

Comment: oh, nice! is it easy to adjust that? what program should I user?

Comment: Sorry, responding very late to this. If you want to adjust a font I would recommend using the app "Glyphs" for Mac. A lot of the software in the font creation space can be expensive, but that app is affordable.